# How do I write a path matcher that matches any part of the remaining path with a regex?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

I'd like to write a path matcher that matches any of the remaining parts of the path with a regex, so for example,

```
path("myregex".r)
```

would match if i have remaining paths in the form:

```
/myregex
/foo/myregex
/foo/myregex/bar
/myregex/bar
```

I looked at the code for the regex matcher, it seems like it only looks at the first segment, I could setup multiple routes or write a custom matcher, but was wondering if there is already a better solution for it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
  path(Segments){segments=>
    validate(segments.exists(_.matches("myregex")), "unmatched path"){          
      complete(s"matched: $segments")
    }
  }
```

Comment: that's it, i think you just opened my eyes to a whole lot of wrong I was previously trying to do :)

Comment: That would be one solution. However, failing `validate` does not result in the same HTTP error code as directly using a custom PathMatcher.